# postgreSql optimisation query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have a postgreSql data base.

In this database i have two tables with the same Foreignkey (who is User)

so i have a table A (list of all user) and a table B (list of user i follow)

and i would like to filter the table A and also add a new colomn who tell me if the user is in the table B or not.

For the moment i do this in multiple task :

- first i get the filter list of user in the table A
- second i get the filter list of user in the table B
- third i parse the table A and for each user i check if it is present or not in the table B

My question is :
can i do this more efficiently ?? in one query for exemple ?

I hope i am clear enough

thank you in advance for your answer

I try to optimise my code
If someone have an idea I'm all ears

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn think in terms of sets instead of sequence of events. You issue then becomes *update tablea indicating if users are also in tableb*.  That can be done in  single update (after adding the appropriate column) with [exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS). (I assume the Foreign key mentioned is not to each other but a third table). (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_6rJTvgR))

```
-- one time action
alter table tablea add column in_tableb boolean default false;

--  recurring update 
update tablea a 
   set in_tableb = exists ( select null 
                              from tableb b 
                             where b.user_id = a.user_id
                          );
```